# Remove everything before a string with bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, ffmpeg

I'm doing this with ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/petaire/GDrive/Taff/ASI/Bash/testFolder/SilenceAndBlack.mp4 -af silencedetect=d=2 -f null - 2>&1 | grep silence_duration
```

And my output is :

```
[silencedetect @ 0x7f9e6940eba0] silence_end: 25.92 | silence_duration: 25.936
```

But I only want to keep the duration number, so I'm trying to remove everything before the last number.

I've never understood anything about sed/awk & co, so I dont know what is the best way to do that. I thought grep would be powerful enough, but it doesn't seems so.

Any idea?

Comment: `... | grep silence_duration | sed 's/.*silence_duration: //'`

Comment: You could use a PCRE if you have GNU grep: `grep -oP '(?<=silence_duration: )[\d.]+'`

Comment: Thanks, the  | sed 's/.*silence_duration: //' is working !

Comment: @petaire, you can add your own answer and accept it, if codeforester does not want to provide one..

Comment: @codeforester, don't pipe grep to sed, and don't repeat yourself:  `... | sed -n '/.*silence_duration: /s///p'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove everything before the last number
you can use

```
grep -o "[^ ]*$"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using awk to print the last field:

```
$ awk '{print $NF}'
```

Test it:

```
$ echo "[silencedetect @ 0x7f9e6940eba0] silence_end: 25.92 | silence_duration: 25.936"| awk '{print $NF}'
25.936
```

or use `sed` to replace everything up to last space with nothing:

```
$ ... | sed 's/.* //'
```

Comment: If we don't assume that "silence_duration" is at the end of the line: `awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i == "silence_duration:") {print $(i+1); exit}'`

Answer (score 3):

you can change your grep command to

```
grep -oP '(?<=silence_duration: )\S+'
```

which will print the next field to the searched one.

Comment: I know the OP didn't say under what OS, however this doesn't work with BSD grep (no -P option) but does work with GNU grep. Nice answer +1

Comment: You can also use PCRE's `\K` ("keep") to make that (GNU-only) grep command much cleaner and simpler: `grep -oP 'silence_duration: \K\S+'`

Comment: "simpler" is in the eye of the beholder.  I find lookbehind/lookahead simpler than magic `\K`. Since Perl sets the gold standard for regex I'm sure it's futile to resist...

Answer (score 2):

Another option, `grep -o` with `cut`:

```
$ echo '[silencedetect @ 0x7f9e6940eba0] silence_end: 25.92 | silence_duration: 25.936' \
    | grep -o 'silence_duration: [0-9]*\.[0-9]*' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
25.936
```